# Parent variable not updated when updating trough child component

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, textfield

I am trying to create a few custom form fields for my page and i learned that i cannot use props to do so so i am trying to find a way to update my parent component variable when i use my child component. Whe i check the parent variable it is always empty.

Here is my component:

```
<template>
    <input
        v-model="value"
        :placeholder="placeHolder"
        class="form-field"
    >
</template>
<script>
export default {
    props: ['placeHolder'],
    data() {
      return {
          value: ''
      }
    },
    methods: {
        updateValue(){
            this.$emit("update-text", this.value);
        }
    },
    watch: {
        value: function(){
            this.updateValue
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

And this is how i use the component:

```
<TextField placeholder="Nome" :update-text="name = value"/>
```

what exactly am i doing wrong?
I am using vue.js with nuxt.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a simpler approach in this case might be emitting an `input` event from your custom text field and binding the component to the variable using `v-model`.

**TextField.vue**

```
<template>
    <input
        @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"
        :placeholder="placeHolder"
        class="form-field"
    >
</template>
<script>
export default {
    props: ['placeHolder']
}
</script>
```

**Usage**

```
<template>
    <TextField placeholder="Nome" v-model="name"/>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data: () => ({
        name: '',
    }),
}
</script>
```

Read more about using `v-model` on custom components [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components).